# How to use newer version libc?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

When I import a module in python, I find:

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/tools/root6/lib/libPyROOT.so)
```

And I have a newer version in `/home/user/.linuxbrew/lib64`, but if I `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/.linuxbrew/lib64` I got a `Segmentation fault`

Is there any way to solve `Segmentation fault` error or just use the newer version `libc`

my os is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Comment: Tried but failed again. maybe I should add a link in `/lib64`? but I don't have root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem recently. Here is what I have done and it works for me: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/.linuxbrew/lib /home/user/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so /abs/path/to/python`. I recommend to make the script above, or add `rpath` and `elf interpreter` using `patchelf` command.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way out of your access level with this. Apologies if this is not possible for you. I was researching this same issue with our db stack as we were upgrading to a newer db version that required a newer version of glibc. What I found was that the most practical, easiest solution for us was to upgrade to CentOS7. I hope that helps.